# How to access a php file in different domains

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on Core PHP by using javascript. In this module I need access from the one domain the other domain, hosting the PHP file, by using Javascript to store the data in database. I'm accessing the file upto js  (everybody can access, it's not an issue ) from domain to domain. But after sharing the data, I need to go to the PHP file to store data.

```
if (message != '') {
    $.post(baseUrl+"chat.php?action=sendchat", {
      to: chatboxtitle, message: message} , function(data){ }
```

JS: Chat.js & jquery.js
CSS: Chat.css

Domain 2 Accessing the Chat.js in the Domain1 but it's not accessing the chat.php file

Comment: If you are doing cross-domain requests, you need to enable this on the server side.  Look up `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ... this needs to be enabled on the server side response to an `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: how i'l enable on server side that Access-Control-Allow-Origin ?

Comment: Look it up - there are tutorials on it!

Comment: Tnq #raduation  by your help i was find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the CORS header 'access-control-allow-origin' to solve the problem.

Firstly you need to add the .htaccess file where the php file is located with the following code.

```
    # Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

I hope if anybody face this problem this is helpful to you....

Answer (score 1):

It's better to access using curl instead of sending request to other domain from java-script which browser will not allow cross-domain request until unless other domain header allowing cross-orgin request.

so you can create one more php file in your server and send ajax request to that file and from there use curl client to connect another domain which proper and secure way to do.

Comment: Can i know how to use that cUrl in between domains

Comment: Create PHP file in you server and send ajax request to that file in that file use following code.  <?php 
        // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch);     
?>

Comment: Did you know how to Run Session on server side... I'm trying to run on server side through CORS. Is it possible?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you why you want session on server side.. if you are looking for solution like manipulating dependent request at server sider.. better go with db base like generating random key and store in db and use that for mauplation...